# Turning text to equation in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel column cells (about 100 cells), contain some numbers as a text

'10+20+30+40

How can i replace the apostrophe (') before numbers by equal (=) to convert it to equation

Regards,
Thanks.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Excel function that evaluates a string as if it were a formula?](https://superuser.com/q/253353)

Comment: Are the delimiters always just a '+'?

Comment: in this case, Yes

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the affected cells can easily be replaced with formulas via the following VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TextToFormula()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Item As Range
    Dim str As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set rng = Application.Selection
    rng.ClearFormats
    For Each Item In rng
        str = "=" & Item.Formula
        If IsNumeric(Evaluate(str)) Then
            Item.Formula = str
        End If
    Next Item
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 13 Then
        MsgBox "Please select one or more cells to be converted.", _
            vbExclamation, "Invalid Selection"
        Else
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Runtime Error: " & Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

This procedure is based on selected cells (`Application.Selection`), so just select the desired range to be converted, then run the macro. You can also insert a button or shape at the top of your worksheet and assign the macro to it for quicker access.

In regards to the apostrophes, you do not need to worry about them. Leading apostrophes are part of the cell formatting and will not be present in the `Range.Formula` string. FYI, they typically show up when data has been exported from another program or database, and can easily be removed by clearing formats (`Range.ClearFormats`; or, on the Ribbon, go to the **Home Tab > Editing Group > Clear > Clear Formats**).

Answer (score 0):

Just go into the Define Name dialog and create this:

[image: Define Name]

That is `=LAMBDA(x,EVALUATE("="&x))`.

Then you can write this: `=EV("10+20+30+40")` in your spreadsheet and it will produce `100`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get some useful insight into the difficulties following  `Brian61354270`'s link and the link that answer includes at the beginning for more.

You have clearly tried a straightforward `Find and Replace` and it did not work or you'd've phrased the "how do I replace" part of the question differently.

Excel carries over a Lotus 1-2-3 convention for justifying cell contents:

```
`'` places content starting at the left edge of the cell
`^` centers the content
`"` has it hard against the right edge of the cell
```

and when it has the character, even though it is visible, since it is NOT part of the cell data contents, but rather is part of its formatting information, the character is not accessible to you via `Find and Replace`.

However, if you are willing to use a "helper column" or to insert another sheet to do the work, then delete it when finished ("helper sheet"), it is trivial to solve the problem.

First set up a formula to concatenate an equals character with the cell's contents. Its result would then be "=10+20+30+40". Copy the result, or column of results, to the Clipboard and then paste overtop it, or overtop the original, using `Paste|Special|Values`. You will have that string, including the "=" as the contents of the cell and it will also be a real boy! As in, you have the contents intact, so can always see the original work, and it has a working formula led off by a working "=" before the original string.

That takes less time to do than it does to read it here, and can be very quick after doing it a couple times.

A note about some of what you will read in the two linked questions. Some answers refer to a function called `EVALUATE` and laud it, or deride it, even claiming it does not work. It DOES work, they just don't use it correctly. It is a command in the last Excel macro set before they switched over to VBA. So you must save the file as an XLXM file if you use it or the next time you open it, Excel will strip it from your file. Much more importantly, it cannot be used in a sheet's cells like all the functions you are used to. So no `=EVALUATE(A1)` placed in cell B1 as part of the work. You must place the formula in a Named Range you define, then refer to the Named Range in the cell formula. (One of the folks claiming it doesn't work actually has a screenshot of him trying to use it inside a normal cell formula... well yeah, that won't work.)

However, while that function and several others that used to be very handy still work, Excel has finally begun taking actual measures to make these nice things go away and surely means to have them gone for real soon(-ish). They've said they might for decades (27-28 years now and counting) and have not, but lately I've seen three or so actual measures to very much discourage their use and that can only be preparatory to really cutting them out, root and branch.

So if you use it, you could find you have a problem in a year or ten.

And one slight tick against it anyway, in this case, and only if important to you, is that you really get it evaluated, to the point that only the result will exist in the cell when done. The `Concatenate and then F&R` approach above shows the result, and it is available to any other cell or formula that refers to it as well, but keeps the original content which might sometimes matter to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still not working, excel sees it  =10+20+30+40 as a text not as a equation, i have an idea, but i do not know how to do it, could i use VBA macro to solve the problem ?, I need a code, every time i select some cells and hit run macro, macro will remove the apostrophe and put = instead